# Comparing two columns in two files using awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to compare two different files, let's say "file1" and "file2", in this way.
If fields $2 and $3 are the same in both files, print $0 of file2. Here's an example:

```
file1
E 352 697 
E 25 692
E 510 744

file2
E 335 705 1 1
E 267 792 1 2
E 365 395 1 3
E 25 692 1 4
E 566 624 1 5
E 227 358 1 6
E 516 554 1 7
E 510 744 1 8
E 234 790 1 9
E 352 697 1 10
```

Desired output:

```
E 352 697 1 10
E 25 692 1 4
E 510 744 1 8
```

Notice that all couples $2,$3 in file1 are contained in file2 and the number of rows of the output file is the same of file1.
There are a lot of questions with similar problems, I know that, but all the answers were not useful. 
I have tried to use:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]; b[$3]; next} $2 in a && $3 in b' file1 file2 > output
```

It works but in the output file there are extra rows. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: But the script gave me the desired output. What do you mean by extra rows?

Comment: I have put just some lines of the files, the original ones are much bigger.. It means that in the output file there are rows present in file2, not on file1. I suppose it is because $2 or $3 are present in file1 but not simultaneously

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2,$3];next} ($2,$3) in a' file1 file2
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. Actually it was similar to my first trial but I had made some mistakes in the syntax.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) print}' file1 file2
E 25 692 1 4
E 510 744 1 8
E 352 697 1 10
```

It store the `file1` in array `a`.  Then loop trough `file2` and test if it contains the data from array `a`, if yes, print the line.

Comment: No it doesn't, it just produces the output you expect from the currently posted sample input. It will fail with other input sets, e.g. when file1 contains a line like `E 352 69`.

Comment: @EdMorton I understand why it should not work from your comment, but if I change `f1` to `E 352 69` it does not print the line and gives same output as your solution.  Can you help me to understand why it seems to work, when it should not work.

Comment: There's probably white space at the end of the line in file1.

Comment: @EdMorton You are always correct, there was a space... Thanks