# Match 2 columns in 2 files and get another value from the first file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I have 2 csv files which have the following structure:

```
File 1:
date,keyword,location,page
2019-04-11,ABC,mumbai,http://www.insurers.com
and so on.

File 2:
date,site,market,location,url 
2019-05-12,denmark,de ,Frankfurt,http://lufthansa.com
2019-04-11,Netherlands,nl,amsterdam,http://www.insurers.com
```

The problem is I need to match the dates in both the files as well as the the url. Example:

```
2019-04-11 and http://www.insurers.com (File 1)
with 
2019-04-11 and http://www.insurers.com (File 2)
```

Edit:
If this condition is satisfied the keyword (`ABC`) in File 1 should be inserted into the File 2 as the third column(new column).

Expected Output:

```
date,site,keyword,market,location,url
2019-04-11,Netherlands,ABC,nl,amsterdam,http://www.insurers.com
```

I have tried putting the dates and urls in a map in java, but there are too many URLs duplicated.
So I am seeking a bash, awk, grep or sed solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two columns in two files using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637951/comparing-two-columns-in-two-files-using-awk)

Comment: @kvantour it's not a dup of that because the keys have to be together as a pair in both files (that other question treats them independently) and the OP has just informed us in his latest edit that the desired output is actually a modification of one of the input files.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry but I think this is a dupe, although maybe in the reverse direction. I'm just wondering where the limit is between a duplicate and not a duplicate. The key part of the question is the same.

Comment: @kvantour the 2 questions seem very different to me (matching a pair of keys from 1 line vs matching 2 individual keys from any lines) and then saving a value to use to modify the output. But we all have opinions... Oh hang on, I was looking at the OPs code in the question, not the solution. You might be right apart from the part about modifying the output. IMHO it's different enough to not be a dup but now I see where you're coming from.

Comment: @EdMorton But the key points of both your answers are identical. "Create an array with a double key.  Find a match. What you do with the content of the array is irrelevant and more upto the user? The reason I mention this is because I notice we get a lot of questions which seem different but are identical if you strip it down to the bare fundamentals.

Comment: @EdMorton Here is yet another example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738914/

Comment: @kvantour Like I say, I understand where you're coming from and I have noticed that about 20% of the questions we get come down to `NR==FNR{a[x];next} y in a` solutions but IMHO it's not obvious how to insert a new field in the middle of the output and that's not shown in either of the questions you suggested this being a dup of and so it's reasonable to keep this particular one open. Just my opinion of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR { m[$1,(NR>1?$4:"url")]=$2; next }
    ($1,$5) in m { $2=$2 OFS m[$1,$5]; print }
' file1 file2
date,site,keyword,market,location,url
2019-04-11,Netherlands,ABC,nl,amsterdam,http://www.insurers.com
```

Answer (score 0):

try gnu sed:

```
sed -En 's!^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]+-[0-9]+,).+(http://\w.+)!s#^\1([^,]+),[^,]+,\\s*\2#\\1#p!p' File2| sed -Enf - File1 >Result
```