# AWK - How to column match multiple matches in file A match one in File B

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to find matching strings between column 1 in file A and column 2 in file B and print the entire row of file A + file B for every match. The problem is there are multiple strings with the same value in column 1 of file A and when I use an awk solution it only prints the last match instead of all matches.

I've tried to use an awk solution I've used before for matching unique values in file A and file B

```
awk -vOFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in a) {print a[$2],$0}' file A file B
```

File A

```
MLLT3   26.53051423 54.24992354 25.50216856
MLLT3   24.32536694 19.96855016 177.7584507
MLLT3   18.9883621  15.83462512 115.2035222
MLLT3   11.79811105 42.91062427 77.35888553
```

File B

```
ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
```

Expected Output:

```
MLLT3   26.53051423 54.24992354 25.50216856 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
MLLT3   24.32536694 19.96855016 177.7584507 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
MLLT3   18.9883621  15.83462512 115.2035222 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
MLLT3   11.79811105 42.91062427 77.35888553 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
```

Actual Output:

```
MLLT3   11.79811105 42.91062427 77.35888553 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.00532152
```

I'm open to any solution, I've just used awk for this type of problem in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use awk at all for this. It's what [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) is designed for:

```
$ join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 file1.tsv file2.tsv               
MLLT3   26.53051423 54.24992354 25.50216856 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
MLLT3   24.32536694 19.96855016 177.7584507 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
MLLT3   18.9883621  15.83462512 115.2035222 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
MLLT3   11.79811105 42.91062427 77.35888553 ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052 3.929504522 3.005321522
```

This assumes that the files are sorted on the relevant fields. If not:

```
$ join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 <(sort -t $'\t' -k1 file1.tsv) <(sort -t $'\t' -k2 file2.tsv)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since keys are repeated in fileA but not in fileB, try:

```
$ awk -vOFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next} ($1 in a) {print $0,a[$1]}' fileB fileA
MLLT3   26.53051423     54.24992354     25.50216856     ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052     3.929504522     3.005321522
MLLT3   24.32536694     19.96855016     177.7584507     ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052     3.929504522     3.005321522
MLLT3   18.9883621      15.83462512     115.2035222     ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052     3.929504522     3.005321522
MLLT3   11.79811105     42.91062427     77.35888553     ENSG00000171843 MLLT3   3.885477052     3.929504522     3.005321522
```