# Compare two numerical ranges in two distincts files with awk and print ALL lines from file1 and the matching ones from file2

Tags: awk

This new question is a followup from a recent question : [Compare two numerical ranges in two distincts files with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016447/compare-two-numerical-ranges-in-two-distincts-files-with-awk/72016949#72016949). The proposed solution that perfectly worked was not practical for downstream analysis (misconception of my question, not on the solution that worked).

I have a file1 with 3 columns. Columns 2 and 3 define a numerical range. Data are sorted from the smaller to the bigger value in column 2. Numerical ranges never overlap.

file1

```
S   24     96
S   126    352
S   385    465
S   548    600
S   621    707
S   724    736
```

I have a second file2 (test) structured similarly.

file2

```
S   27     93
S   123    348
S   542    584
S   726    740
S   1014   2540
S   12652  12987
```

Desired output: Print ALL lines from file1 and next to them, lines of file2 for which numerical ranges overlap (including partially) the ones of file1. If no ranges from file2  overlap to a range of file1, print zero next to the range of file 1.

```
S   24    96     S   27    93       * 27-93 overlaps with 24-96
S   126   352    S   123   355      * 123-355 overlaps with 126-352
S   385   465    0                  * nothing in file2 overlaps with this range
S   548   600    S   542   584      * 542-584 overlaps with 548-600
S   621   707    0                  * nothing in file2 overlaps with this range
S   724   736    S   726   740      * 726-740 overlaps with 724-736
```

Based on the answer of the previous question from @EdMorton I modified the print command of the tst.awk script to add these new features. In addition I also changed the order file1/file2 to file2/file1 to have all the lines from file1 printed (whether or not there is a match in the second file)

```
'NR == FNR {
begs2ends[$2] = $3
next
}
{
for (beg in begs2ends) {
    end = begs2ends[beg] + 0
    beg += 0
    if (    ( ($2 >= beg) && ($2 <= end) ) ||
            ( ($3 >= beg) && ($3 <= end) ) ||
            ( ($2 <= beg) && ($3 >= end) )  ) {
        print $0,"\t",$1,"\t",beg,"\t",end
    else 
        print $0,"\t","0"
        next
    }
}
}
```

Note: $1 is identical in file1 and file2. This is why I used print ... $1 to make it appear. No idea how to print it from file2 and not file1 (if I understand correctly this $1 refers to file1.

And I launch the analysis with awk -f tst.awk file2 file1

The script is not accepting the `else` argument and I dont understand why? I assuming that it is linked to the looping but I tried several changes without any success.
Thanks if you can help me with this.

Comment: the `else` logic (ie, `print $0,"\t","0"`) must come after the `for` loop has been exhausted (ie, no overlaps found); the `next` should remain as part of the `if` (as in the answer to your previous question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- a range from `file1` can only overlap with one range from `file2`

The current code is almost correct, just need some work with the placement of the braces (using some consistent indentation helps):

```
awk '
BEGIN     { OFS="\t" }                                 # output field delimiter is "\t"
NR == FNR { begs2ends[$2] = $3; next } 
          {
            # $1=$1                                    # uncomment to have current line ($0) reformatted with "\t" delimiters during print
            for (beg in begs2ends) {
                end = begs2ends[beg] + 0
                beg += 0
               if ( ( ($2 >= beg) && ($2 <= end) ) ||
                    ( ($3 >= beg) && ($3 <= end) ) ||
                    ( ($2 <= beg) && ($3 >= end) ) ) {
                  print $0,$1,beg,end                  # spacing within $0 unchanged, 3 new fields prefaced with "\t"
                  next
               }
            }

            # if we get this far it is because we have exhausted the "for" loop
            # (ie, found no overlaps) so print current line + "0"

            print $0,"0"                               # spacing within $0 unchanged, 1 new field prefaced with "\t"
          }
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
S   24     96   S       27      93
S   126    352  S       123     348
S   385    465  0
S   548    600  S       542     584
S   621    707  0
S   724    736  S       726     740
```

With the `$1=$1` line uncommented the output becomes:

```
S       24      96      S       27      93
S       126     352     S       123     348
S       385     465     0
S       548     600     S       542     584
S       621     707     0
S       724     736     S       726     740
S       900     1000    S       901     905
```

Comment: Dear markp-fuso, Many thanks for your detailed and inspiring help. I particularly apreciate the comments that help me to understand and progress :-) Very much appreciated. One tiny thing: the "S" that appears in "This generates" is not from file2 but from file1. I know that because in my 2 test files (file1 and file2) I changed the S (column 1) of file2 to the letter P and I still have the letter S that appears in the output. Any idea why?

Comment: @Opus_francigenum if you care which file the `S` comes from then don't use the same letter for both files in your sample input/output so we can see and test that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on @markp-fuso's answer

Works with GNU awk: saved as `overlaps.awk`

```
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" }
function in_range(val, min, max) { return min <= val && val <= max }
NR == FNR {
    line[FNR] = $0
    lo[FNR] = $2
    hi[FNR] = $3
    next
}
{
    overlap = "0"
    for (i in line) {
        if (in_range(lo[i], $2, $3) || in_range(hi[i], $2, $3)) {
            overlap = line[i]
            delete line[i]
            break
        }
    }
    print $0, overlap
}
```

Then

```sh
gawk -f overlaps.awk file2 file1 | column -t
```

outputs

```
S  24   96   S  27   93
S  126  352  S  123  348
S  385  465  0
S  548  600  S  542  584
S  621  707  0
S  724  736  S  726  740
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR == FNR {
    ranges[++numRanges] = $0
    next
}
{
    overlapped = 0
    for ( i=1; i<=numRanges; i++ ) {
        range = ranges[i]
        split(range,vals)
        beg = vals[2]+0
        end = vals[3]+0
        if (    ( ($2 >= beg) && ($2 <= end) ) ||
                ( ($3 >= beg) && ($3 <= end) ) ||
                ( ($2 <= beg) && ($3 >= end) )  ) {
            overlapped = 1
            break
        }
    }

    if ( overlapped ) {
        print $0, range, sprintf("* %d-%d overlaps with %d-%d", beg, end, $2, $3)
    }
    else {
        print $0, 0, sprintf("* nothing in %s overlaps with this range", ARGV[1])
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1 | column -s$'\t' -t
S   24     96   S   27     93   * 27-93 overlaps with 24-96
S   126    352  S   123    348  * 123-348 overlaps with 126-352
S   385    465  0               * nothing in file2 overlaps with this range
S   548    600  S   542    584  * 542-584 overlaps with 548-600
S   621    707  0               * nothing in file2 overlaps with this range
S   724    736  S   726    740  * 726-740 overlaps with 724-736
```