# Print lines of file1 if four specific strings DO NOT match a list of strings in file2

Tags: awk

I want to print lines of file1 when columns 1, 2, 4, and 5 DO NOT match columns 1, 2, 4, and 5 in file2.

File1 (sample):

```
1   24  .   A   T   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   false
1   107 .   T   A   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
2   33  .   C   CA  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   false
5   18  .   G   GG  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
5   49  .   A   AAA 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
```

File2 (database):

```
1   55  .   C   T
1   107 .   T   A
2   15  .   G   C
2   98  .   C   T
2   102 .   G   T
3   25  .   T   A
5   84  .   A   AA
5   49  .   A   AAA
```

The desired output:

```
1   24  .   A   T   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   false
2   33  .   C   CA  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   false
5   18  .   G   GG  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
```

What I've done so far is adapted from the answer of Ed Morton (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27640964/16425907) with a slight modification  (not in a versus in a) :

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1 "\t" $2 "\t" $4 "\t" $5];next} ($1,$2,$4,$5) not in a' file1 file2 > output
```

The script does not execute because of a syntax error >> not << that is not recognised. Any suggestion to either print lines that ARE NOT in file2 or delete lines of file1 that ARE in file2?

Comment: "not in" should be written as: `!(($1,$2,$4,$5) in a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all Algol-based languages AFAIK, the awk negation operator is `!`.

When you have a list of more than 2 fields as a common key across input files, or need to reference the key more than 2 times, create a variable to hold the list rather than duplicating it to reduce the odds of a bug creeping in and make it easy to update the list later if/when necessary (e.g. add/remove a field or make it case-independent or anything else):

```
$ awk '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5} NR==FNR{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' file2 file1
1   24  .   A   T   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   false
2   33  .   C   CA  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   false
5   18  .   G   GG  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
```

Set FS to tab if you like, it's not necessary given your posted sample input as you have no empty fields.

Comment: I tested this solution with my files (that are much larger than the examples) and it perfectly worked. Thanks for the help and for the explanations that help me to be more autonomous.

Answer (score 2):

This gives the correct answer with your example data:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5]; next} !(($1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5) in a)' file2 file1
1   24  .   A   T   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   false
2   33  .   C   CA  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   false
5   18  .   G   GG  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
```

---

Or you could use `,` or `"\t"` in between CHR POS REF ALT and get the same output, e.g.

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$4,$5]; next} !(($1,$2,$4,$5) in a)' file2 file1
1   24  .   A   T   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   false
2   33  .   C   CA  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   false
5   18  .   G   GG  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read `file2` first since it's that file you use to build the lookup table. You also need to check if the lookup table contains the element you search for. It can look like this:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5];next}{
    if(!(($1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5) in a)) print}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
1       24      .       A       T       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       false
2       33      .       C       CA      0       0       0       0       0       0       2       false
5       18      .       G       GG      0       0       0       0       0       0       1       false
```